# In what order do filter attributes run?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When adding a filter attribute such as `OutputCacheAttribute` to an action and overriding the `OnActionExecuting` method of the controller, which runs first? Is there a document of the full MVC lifestyle anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html

To summarize: pre-action filters (`OnActionExecuting`, `OnAuthorization`, etc) run top down while post-action fitlers (`OnActionExecuted`, `OnResultExecuting`, etc) run bottom up.